# MariaDB Crashes on Startup with Let's Encrypt Certificates

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb, lets-encrypt, certbot

It seems I'm encountering an issue while setting up secure connections for my clients to connect to my database server on Debian 12. Every time I attempt to start MariaDB, it crashes with a `Private key does not match the certificate public key` error. Despite attempting to regenerate the certificate and key using the following command: 'certbot certonly --key-type rsa --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials /etc/cloudflare/credential.ini -d db1.mydomain.com', I'm still facing the same issue. I've verified the integrity of the private key, and it appears to be fine (RSA key ok).

Additionally, I moved the certificate and key to /etc/mysql/certs and gave the ownership to the MySQL user with 0700 permissions. Below, I've included the logs and configuration file for reference. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Full log:

```
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost systemd[1]: Starting mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.11.6 database server...
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.6-MariaDB-0+deb12u1 source revision  as process 7080
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
Feb 11 23:32:17 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=7416428985935
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 7416428985935; transaction id 492398711
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: SSL error: Private key does not match the certificate public key
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [ERROR] Failed to setup SSL
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [ERROR] SSL error: Private key does not match the certificate public key
Feb 11 23:32:19 myhost mariadbd[7080]: 2024-02-11 23:32:19 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

50-server.cnf

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mariadbd daemon
[mariadbd]

#
# * Basic Settings
#

user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp

# Broken reverse DNS slows down connections considerably and name resolve is
# safe to skip if there are no "host by domain name" access grants
skip-name-resolve

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = *

#
# * Fine Tuning
#

key_buffer_size        = 256M
max_allowed_packet     = 5G
thread_stack           = 256K
thread_cache_size      = 1024
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP,FORCE
max_connections        = 500
table_cache            = 4096

#
# * Logging and Replication
#

# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# Recommend only changing this at runtime for short testing periods if needed!
#general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log            = 1

# Error logging goes via stdout/stderr, which on systemd systems goes to
# journald.
# Enable this if you want to have error logging into a separate file
#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_query_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#log_slow_query_time    = 10
#log_slow_verbosity     = query_plan,explain
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_min_examined_row_limit = 1000

# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replica, see README.Debian about other
#       settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
#max_binlog_size        = 100M

#
# * SSL/TLS
#

# For documentation, please read
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/certs/chain.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/certs/cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/certs/privkey.pem
#require-secure-transport = on

#
# * Character sets
#

# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * InnoDB
#

# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
# Most important is to give InnoDB 80 % of the system RAM for buffer use:
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadbd]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-11.2 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-11.2]
```

Comment: Calculate the hashes of the public and private key and see if they match to double check / verify `if [ "$(openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -outform PEM | sha256sum)" = "$(openssl rsa -pubin -in public_key.pem -pubout -outform PEM | sha256sum)" ]; then echo "Keys match"; else echo "Keys do not match"; fi`

Comment: I've generated a new public key with OpenSSL `openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -pubout > key.pub`, and the keys match. However, I'm uncertain if this is the correct approach since I generated the public key myself. Additionally, I didn't have to add a public key in the MariaDB configuration.

Comment: Yes that's also what i came across on the letsencrypt forums that you have to generate the keys yourself, locally. You already have public key right `ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/certs/cert.pem `

Comment: Inside `/etc/mysql/certs/cert.pem` is the private certificate. With Nginx, for instance, I never had to generate a public key. Additionally, the public key is for clients to connect to the server, so I'm unsure about what to do with the public key on the server itself.

Comment: I found the issue: for some reason, my my.cnf was empty, so 50-server.cnf wasn't read during startup.